# How to save document with type "Reference" in Firestore using Python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to save in firestore using python, a document with exactly type reference

I know in js, you can doing something like this:

```js
let data = {
  name: 'productName',
  size: 'medium',
  userRef: db.doc('users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
};
db.collection('products').add(data);
```

userRef being the reference.

what's in python the way to doing: 
`db.doc('users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)`

Comment: There are lots of examples of creating document reference objects in the documentation.  Are you saying that doesn't work for you?  Can you show what you tried that didn't work?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Answer (score 1):

Passing the document reference as the value in set() works. Example:

```
reference = db.collection('Company').document('Apple') 
db.collection('Product').document('iPhone').set({"company_id":reference},merge=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection('users').document(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
```

I had the same question. in my case the follwoing case worked. Firebase recognize the Reference.

```
        batch = db.batch()
        for i in request.json['data']:
          i['ref'] = db.collection(u'component').document(i["supplier_item_number"])
          batch.set(stock_ref.document(), i)
        batch.commit()
```